# angular template src variable not working

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

videoSrc variable not evaluating properly

```
images/{{videoSrc}}.mp4
```

if i'm writing only videoSrc then its working propely but while concating with other string it is not working

see [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/0p223fbj/1/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use template: fn way see example bellow

```
angular.module('myApp', []).directive('videoPopup', function() {
    return {
        strict: 'A',
        scope: {
            videoSrc: '@'
        },
        replace:true,
        template: function(tElem, tAttrs){
            return '<video width="100%" controls><source 
src="images/'+tAttrs.videoSrc+'.mp4" type="video/mp4"><source src="images/'+tAttrs.videoSrc+'.webm" type="video/webm"></video>'

        } 
    }
});
```

[working fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/0p223fbj/5/)

Answer (score 1):

Yeah interpolating `src` or `ng-src` in `video` seems broken, you'll probably best off creating the elements by hand in your directive's link function whenever `videoSrc` changes.